# Font Awesome vue js Layers creates artifact that causes unwanted spacing in Vue Bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I'm noticing that when using code like this:

```
<b-row>
    <font-awesome-layers full-width> <!--class="fa-lg"-->
        <font-awesome-icon icon="print"/>
        <font-awesome-icon icon="check" transform="left-20" :style="{ color: 'red' }" />
    </font-awesome-layers>
    <b-button variant="success">
        <font-awesome-layers full-width> <!--class="fa-lg"-->
            <font-awesome-icon icon="print"/>
            <font-awesome-icon icon="check" transform="left-20" :style="{ color: 'red' }" />
        </font-awesome-layers>
    </b-button>
</b-row>
```

That the layered icon I am including has a leftover artifact/spacing for where it originally was before getting transformed. These screenshots I think help illustrate what I am seeing:

[image]

[image]

You can see that in the first case, there is a gap before the button begins, which isn't terrible, but in the second case, the button is way wider than it needs/should be. This looks really bad and I can't seem to get it to go away.

Edit versions:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.2",
"@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
"@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.2.0",
"@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.2.0",
"@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.1",

"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.26",
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved/hacked for this by adding some styling to my button:

```
style="width:30%;max-height:34px;"
```

and transforming the layer differently, so:

```
                    <b-button variant="success" v-b-tooltip.hover title="Mark as printed." style="width:30%;max-height:34px;">
                        <font-awesome-layers full-width> <!--class="fa-lg"-->
                            <font-awesome-icon icon="print"/>
                            <font-awesome-icon icon="check" transform="up-22" :style="{ color: 'red' }" />
                        </font-awesome-layers>
                    </b-button>
```

I imagine there is a css conflict happening with bootstrap or possibly another library I am using.